# three random numbers which are not equal to each other?

Tags: c++, c, random, logic

I am able to generate three random integer numbers between a range of 0-25. But i have to make certain conditions that these three integers should always have different value to each other i.e. `i != j` ,`j != k` , `k != i` . I have made the following code but i am afraid that it will not satisfy the condition and may also result in infinite loop condition.

```
int i = ts_rint (25); int j = ts_rint (25); int k = ts_rint (25);

    while ( k == i)
    {
        k = ts_rint (25);

        while ( i == j )
        {
            i = ts_rint (25);

            while ( j == k )
            {
                j = ts_rint (25);
            }
        }
    }
```

I am using `TScope` which is a C-libraries to create cognitive experiments. You can have a look [here](http://users.ugent.be/~masteven/tscope/doc/refman_en/node7.html#SECTION00076000000000000000) to see what is `ts_rint(int nMax)`.

**My code got failed at this condtion:**

Original: i = 9 j = 9 k = 11

After While Loop  i: 9 j: 9 k: 11

***So, this while loop system can very very very easily get failed.***

Comment: Don't be afraid.  Try to execute it; if it doesn't work, try to debug it.

Comment: but is the logic correct?

Comment: It will break at some point, so dont be afraid of using it.

Comment: As it is a part of an experiment so, my application cannot wait for too long time.

Comment: No need to re-try all 3 `i,j,k`.  Only need to adjust 2.

Comment: Not worthy of an answer, but if you want random integers between 0 and 25 (up to and including 25), you should be using `ts_rint(26)` rather than `ts_rint(25)`.

Comment: Worth saying, that *almost* all solutions described in answers are complicated and error prone (notably, they add tricky control paths). As always, in this case you must be absolutely sure, that you want to add that complexity in your application. Does it worth it? If your code fails once per zillion years, consider leave it as is, because new code can crash more often due to hidden bugs.

Comment: Pick `i` randomly.  Pick `j` randomly.  If `j == i`, keep picking a new `j` until you find a `j != i`.  Finally pick a `k` randomly.  If it is equal to `i` or `j`, keep picking another until that's not the case.  The only way you could get caught in an infinite loop is to have a bad RNG that kept repeating the same two values.

Answer (score 3):

This is called rejection sampling. It is a fine solution for situations where:

- The rejection is rare and unlikely to take much time.
- A deterministic bound on compute time is not required.
- Directly computing a sample without rejection is difficult.

The loop is indeed unbounded in theory, but, in practice in most situations, it will not be a problem.

It is not necessary to resample all three numbers. You can use this:

```
int i = ts_rint(25), j, k;
do j = ts_rint(25); while (i == j);
do k = ts_rint(25); while (k ==i || k == j);
```

In this case, we are rejecting only part of a sample. (The sample is the combined triple of numbers. We reject only one at a time.) That works in this case. However, with more complicated probability distributions, it is necessary to ensure that the structure of the algorithm produces the desired distribution.

Edit: As other answers have noted, there are ways to generate the desired triples without the possibility of looping. (Thus, the third criterion above is violated; rejection sampling generally should not be used for this problem.) However, as other answers and numerous edits have demonstrated, they appear to be error prone. So check the code carefully.

Now that the other answers have settled down somewhat, I decided to have some fun. Let’s generate the three numbers, in ascending order, directly (without any branches). We can do that with this code:

```
int p = ts_rint(25*24*23/6);
complex double t =
    cpow(372600 - 324*p + 3*csqrt(11664.*p*p-26827200.*p-80590467), 1/3.);
int j = (50 - t/3 - 1729/t - csqrt(-3)*(t/3-1729/t))/4 + 0x1p-20;
int r = p - (69*j - 79 - 2*j*j) * j / 6;
int i = r%j;
int k = r/j;
```

Unfortunately, I am out of time for now, so detailed explanation will have to wait for another day. Briefly, we number the samples from 0 to 2299 (2300 samples, 25•24•23/6). We know *j*•(*n*-*j*-1) samples have *j* as their middle value (because there are *j* lower numbers available for the first value and *n*-*j*-1 higher numbers available for the third value). Then we sum that to determine how many samples have a middle value less than or equal to a particular *j*. Then we set that sum equal to a sample number and solve for *j* as a function of the sample number. That allows us to directly determine *j* from a result of `ts_rint(25*24*23/6)`. After finding *j*, *i* and *k* follow easily. The fun part is sum is a cubic polynomial, so its solution uses complex arithmetic.

In lieu of further derivation, here is a program to demonstrate correctness:

```
#include <complex.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>


#define N   25


int main(void)
{
    int A[N][N][N] = {{{0}}};

    //  First, mark each of the 2300 results we ought to find.
    for (int i = 0;   i < N; ++i)
    for (int j = i+1; j < N; ++j)
    for (int k = j+1; k < N; ++k)
        ++A[i][j][k];

    /*  Next, iterate through each value that ts_rint(25*24*23/6) might return,
        generate a triple for each value, and test for whether we generate each
        required triple exactly once.
    */
    for (int p = 0; p < 25*24*23/6; ++p)
    {
        complex double t =
            cpow(372600 - 324*p + 3*csqrt(11664.*p*p-26827200.*p-80590467), 1/3.);
        int j = (50 - t/3 - 1729/t - csqrt(-3)*(t/3-1729/t))/4 + 0x1p-20;
        int r = p - (69*j - 79 - 2*j*j) * j / 6;
        int i = r%j;
        int k = r/j;

        /*  Given triple (i, j, k), is it one we are supposed to generate, and
            have we not seen it before?
        */
        if (A[i][j][k] != 1)
        {
            printf("Error, A[%d][%d][%d] = %d, p = %d.\n",
                i, j, k, A[i][j][k], p);
            return 1;
        }
        A[i][j][k] = 0;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i tried your code and it entered into an infinite loop and after commenting your code it worked again.

Comment: @skim: What is your `rint` function? Is it the `rint` in `<math.h>` (which is a round-to-integer function), or is it your own function that returns a random integer? Generally, you should avoid uses names that are already defined in standard or common libraries.

Comment: Actually i am using `TScope` which provides c -libraries. Have a look at this link < http://users.ugent.be/~masteven/tscope/doc/refman_en/node7.html#SECTION00076000000000000000 >

Comment: Thanks Eric that you are still testing it. I am also trying to test

Answer (score 3):

Your code works.

As an alternative, you may use:

```
int i = ts_rint(25);
int j = ts_rint(24);
int k = ts_rint(23);
j += j >= i;
k += k >= std::min(i, j);
k += k >= std::max(i, j);
```

Comment: This works. To be sure, I simulated exhaustively with every permutation of values produced by the three `ts_rint` calls, and each possible triple was produced with equal probability.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: thanks for the check. And fixed your comment ^^

Comment: What is the purpose to comparing to `min(i, j)` and `max(i, j)`? Can't you just compare it directly to `i` and `j` and increment?

Comment: @Drop: If you do not test against the lesser of `i` and `j` first, then the first test of `k` might report it does not need to be incremented, but the second test will increment it into conflict. E.g., suppose we replace `min(…)` by plain `i` and `max(…)` by plain `j`, and suppose `i`, `j`, and `k` are 1, 0, and 0. Then `k += k >= i` evaluates to `k += 0`, so `k` remains 0, and `k += k >= j` evaluates to `k += 1`, so `k` becomes 1 and conflicts with `i`. As given in the answer, `k += k >= std::min(i, j)` evaluates to `k += 1`, and then `k += k >= std::max(i, j)` also evaluates to `k += 1`.

Answer (score 1):

If you really only need 3 random integers, you can do something like this:

```
    k = rint (25);

    // only 24 values remaining for i
    i = rint (24);
    // remap k to 24
    if (i == k)
        i = 24;

    // only 23 values remaining for j
    j = rint (23);
    // remap k to 25 (or 24 if it's taken)
    if (j == k)
        j = (i == 24) ? 23 : 24;
    // remap i to 24
    else if (j == i)
        j = (k == 24) ? 23 : 24;
```

If you need to scale this to more values, it's probably better to create a vector  containing all possible values, and removing values from it as they are randomly picked.

Comment: Please explain why this fails.

Comment: If `k` happens to be set to 1 and `i` happens to be set to 1, then `i` is changed to 25. Then, if `j` also happens to be set to 1, it is changed to 25. Then `i` and `j` are both 25.

Comment: good one, thanks (the initial comments saying this failed disappeared)!

Comment: I fixed the problem Eric mentioned, but I don't see the distribution uniformity issue.

Comment: The desired range is [0, 25); 25 is excluded. However, even if that is fixed, consider what happens when `k` is set one less the maximum value, `i` is initially set to 0, and `j` is initially set to 0. Then the `j == i` test at the end sets `j` to one less than the maximum value, duplicating `k`.

Comment: Good point, once again. Will fix for half-open range and other remap, but it's starting to get really messy~

Comment: Suggest `i = rint2(NN); j = rint2(NN-1); k = rint2(NN-2); if (k == j) { k = NN - 2; } if (j == i) { j = NN - 1; } else if (k == i) { k = NN - 1; }`

Answer (score 1):

i want to explain how to have three random numbers without a possibility that they can be equal , i wont give any code;
you need to generate the random number from the interval 0 - 25 without the previous number, example: when you generate i you need to extract k from the interval of 0 - 25
(sorry for bad english)

Answer (score 1):

```
int k = rint(25 * 24 * 23);
int i = k / (24 * 23);
k %= 24 * 23;
int j = k / 23;
k %= 23;

if (j >= i)
{
    ++j;
    if (k >= i)
        ++k;
    if (k >= j)
        ++k;
}
else
{
    if (k >= j)
        ++k;
    if (k >= i)
        ++k;
}
```

Comment: fail when, before the `if`, `i == 3`, `j == 0`, `k == 2`

Comment: @EricPostpischil, thank you, that was a typo. Fixed now.

Comment: This works. To be sure, I simulated exhaustively with every permutation of values produced by the three `ts_rint` calls, and each possible triple was produced with equal probability.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** this solution is wrong and need further improvements, see comments below.

Simple solution without a loops:

```
srand(time(0));

int i = rand() % 25;
int j = rand() % 25;
int k = rand() % 25;

if (i == j) j++;
if (i == k) k++;
if (j == k) k++;
```

(Sorry for `rand()`, it's just taken for brevity)

Comment: @skm Use anything you like, all is about if/increment there. I wasn't just sure that your `rint()` correct.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Catch =) This will be trivially to fix.

Comment: Sorry, never mind; the desired range is [0, 25), per documentation at a URL given in a comment.

Comment: This will not work (even when the range is corrected) because the conditional increments may increment the numbers beyond the desired interval. E.g., if `i`, `j`, and `k` happen to be set initially to the highest desired value 24, then the increments will change `j` and `k` to 25.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Oh... it even change `k` to `26` in case when `24` was generated for both `i` and `j`. So, my algorithm is completely destroyed! Decrementing will not help, as it will push numbers below desired. I hope, we can fix it with some `if`s and still without using loops.

Comment: Still not correct, Drop. It fails if the initial value for k is i-1 and the initial value for j is either i or i-1. For example, i=21, j=20, k=20 means the first two `if` statements evaluate to false, the third to `true`. The result is i=21, j=20, k=21.

Comment: @DavidHammen Catch! =( So order of comparisons matter there.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered basing your solution on a [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)?  The following generates k-tuples in O(k) time, and guarantees distinct outcomes with all elements having equal probability of being selected.  If you need to generate multiple k-tuples there's no need to re-initialize the array - shuffling doesn't depend on the initial ordering to yield uniformly distributed results.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define NUM_VALUES 26

static int values[NUM_VALUES] =
    {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25};

void generate(int n) {
    for(int i = NUM_VALUES - 1; i > NUM_VALUES - (n + 1); --i) {
        int j = arc4random_uniform(i+1);
        if (i != j) {
            int tmp = values[i];
            values[i] = values[j];
            values[j] = tmp;
        }
        printf("%d ", values[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(void) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i) {
        generate(3);
    }
}
```

This could probably be made cleaner, my C is rusty.  My compiler doesn't seem to have `ts_rint()` so I used `arc4random_uniform()` instead, but I think it's a simple substitution for you to replace it.

Answer (score 0):

***Edit: This is an incorrect answer, it fails to yield proper results under bad luck***

```
int i, j, k;

i = ts_rint( 25 );     /*  casually get a random number with 1/26 probability  */
                    /*  you're done with the i                              */

j = ts_rint( 24 );     /*  get a random number with 1/25 probability      */
                    /*  now, this number has the right probability,    */
                    /*  but it was not to be picked from [0, 24]       */
                    /*  rather from [0, 25] \ { i } or in other words  */
                    /*  [0, i - 1] union [i + 1, 25], so...            */
if ( j >= i ) j++;  /*  <<< this will achieve that                     */


k = ts_rint( 23 );     /*  same story, two fold  */
if ( k >= i ) k++;
if ( k >= j ) k++;
```

And bam, all the explanation is given as comments.

<sub>*edit:* incorrect last line from `k >= i` to `k >= j`</sub>

Comment: The duplicated lines `if ( k >= i ) k++;` appear to be a typo. I expect one of them is expected to have `k >= j`, but that still results in an incorrect algorithm.

Comment: You need to fix your algorithm for incrementing k (the last two statements). I'm not down voting yet, but I will be if you don't fix it.

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer, skm. It is wrong!

Comment: @DavidHammen I cannot see any other problem than the typo Eric mentioned... And after having thought over it for 5~10 minutes, I have only been convinced more to it's correctness. Please, explain me what is *wrong* about it, I need to know.

Comment: This code fails when `i` is initially set to 1, `j` is initially set to 0, and `k` is initially set to 0. Then the statement `if ( k >= i ) k++;` does not change `k`, and `if (k >= j ) k++;` changes `k` to 1, leaving it equal to `i`.

Comment: Additionally, the comments have the intervals wrong: `ts_rint(25)` selects a random number in [0, 25) (note the half-open interval) with probability 1/25 each, not 1/26.

Comment: @EricPostpischil as for the intervals, I wrote those knowingly, just went ahead with the description in the question where OP says *"0-25"*, but I understand where it fails